# Match only words (sometimes with dots seperating) regex

Tags: python, regex, dns, ip

I have a list like so:

```
example.com=120.0.0.0
ben.example.com=120.0.0.0
+ben.example=120.0.0.0
+ben.example.com.np=120.0.0.0
ben=120.0.0.0
ben-example.com=120.0.0.0
ben43.example.com=120.0.0.0
```

I need to find only the words (with dots seperated).
No ips, `=, +` and so on.
Some FQDN have multiple dots, some none at all and so on.

Is this possible?

If the script works well when i run the regex i want to get these only:

```
ben.example.com.np
ben.example
ben.example.com
example.com
ben
ben43.example.com
```

I want to parse the file into ips and FQDNS via python regex so i can work with it and check if the ips are available for the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very straightforward

```
import re
fqdns = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z\.-]{2,}", text, flags=re.M)
```

gives

```
['example.com', 'ben.example.com', 'ben.example', 'ben-example.com.np', 'ben']
```

[regex101 example here](https://regex101.com/r/s5hNkb/1)

The group matches all characters in the ranges `a-z` and `A-Z`, along with dot `.` and `-`. The `{2,}` means match at least 2 characters in a row, so it won't match the dots in the IPs.

---

EDIT: After I wrote this answer the parameters of the question changed slightly, as some of the URLs contained numbers. So, instead of using `re.findall()` to get all matches in a (potentially multi-line) input, you should use `re.match().group()` with a slightly altered regex and process the input line by line:

```
import re

with open("path/to/file", "r") as f:
    fqdns = [re.match(r"(?:[a-zA-Z\.\-0-9]{2,})", line).group() for line in f]
```

`re.match()`, in the absence of any flags, returns after the first match in the line. `.group()` is the way you access the matched string.

Comment: Hey, i forgot to mention.
Some have a - in between them too (updating the question.)
Fixed it with adding this: [a-zA-Z\.\-]{2,}

Comment: I just checked and apperantly 2 records in the file have numbers in them too.
Is it possible to parse that too? looks kinda like:
`ben.example43.com`

Comment: @benshalev if you're processing your file line by line, this *should* work: `re.match(r"(?:[a-zA-Z\.\-0-9]{2,})", text).group()`. `re.findall()` doesn't work in this situation because the regex will also recognize the IPs. `re.match()` here will only return the first match in the line.